# How to use vue-template-babel-compiler with laravel vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

How to use this package with laravel 6?
in my laravel project does not have  webpack.config.js.
How use this webpack config with my laravel 6 project

```
    module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
            compiler: require('vue-template-babel-compiler')
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

https://github.com/JuniorTour/vue-template-babel-compiler/blob/main/doc/Usage.md#2-Webpack

thank you.

Sorry for my english